# ORACLE - How can I improve this query?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two tables. One is empty and other one has approximately 20 thousand record. In these records there is Geometry column which uses SDO_PACKAGEs of Oracle. I have to find intersections among these records.
I write pl/sql query that sufficient for me but for only 2 thousand records it consume twenty minutes. I try to complete execution but in 330 minutes there is still going on. So can i improve these query for faster execution.

Sub-Question: In insertion part should i use a buffer and lastly insert via bulk insertion or what else?

Note: I am using oracle 11g and pl/sql developer.
FirstTable has 20000 records. (geometry)
SecondTable initialy empty.

```
declare
control1 number(1);
control2 number(1);
resultForStart varchar2(5);
resultForEnd varchar2(5);
BEGIN
FOR aRow IN (SELECT MI_PRINX, SDO_LRS.geom_segment_start_pt(geoloc) as startpoint, SDO_LRS.geom_segment_end_pt(geoloc) as endpoint FROM FirstTable)
 LOOP
  control1 :=0;
  control2 :=0; 
  FOR bRow IN (SELECT * FROM SecondTable)
   LOOP
    select SDO_GEOM.RELATE(aRow.Startpoint,'anyinteract', SDO_LRS.geom_segment_start_pt(bRow.Geoloc),0.02) into resultForStart from dual;
    select SDO_GEOM.RELATE(aRow.Endpoint,'anyinteract', SDO_LRS.geom_segment_end_pt(bRow.Geoloc),0.02) into resultForEnd from dual;
    if (resultForStart='TRUE' AND control1=0 )
     THEN 
      UPDATE SecondTable SET COUNTER=(bRow.Counter+1) 
            WHERE MI_PRINX=bRow.Mi_Prinx AND STARTEND=bRow.Startend;
    control1 :=1;          
    END IF;
    if (resultForEnd='TRUE' AND control2=0)
     THEN 
      UPDATE SecondTable SET COUNTER=(bRow.Counter+1)
             WHERE MI_PRINX=bRow.Mi_Prinx AND STARTEND=bRow.Startend;
    control2 :=1;
    END IF;           
    EXIT WHEN (control1 > 0 AND control2>0);
   END LOOP;    
  if (control1 = 0) 
   THEN    
    Insert INTO SecondTable (MI_PRINX,STARTEND,GEOLOC) values (aRow.Mi_Prinx,'s',aRow.Startpoint);--default Counter 1
  END IF;
  if (control2 = 0)
   THEN
    Insert INTO SecondTable (MI_PRINX,STARTEND,GEOLOC) values (aRow.Mi_Prinx,'e',aRow.Endpoint);--default Counter 1
  END IF;
  control1 :=0;
  control2 :=0; 
 END LOOP; 
END;
```

Comment: What indexes do you have on SecondTable? You might want to force Oracle to collect optimizer statistics on SecondTable once it gets partly full. Then rerun the PL/SQL procedure and it may run faster due to the stats.

Comment: Don't worry about the inserts, that will not be the issue. It's the action in requerying and updating SecondTable during each cycle of the loop as the table grows. Or just simply the complexity of your algorithm.

Comment: @PeterM. SecondTable's primary key is Mi_Prinx (number(10)) and StartEnd (varchar2(1)): composite primary key. And Mi_Prinx come from FirstTable, it is already defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's on tip: you seem to be reading rows from tables, and then updating them.

```
FOR bRow IN (SELECT * FROM SecondTable)
   LOOP
    ...
    if (resultForStart='TRUE' AND control1=0 )
     THEN 
      UPDATE SecondTable SET COUNTER=(bRow.Counter+1) 
            WHERE MI_PRINX=bRow.Mi_Prinx AND STARTEND=bRow.Startend;
```

If you have to do this, use the rowid instead:

```
FOR bRow IN (SELECT * FROM SecondTable)
   LOOP
    ...
    if (resultForStart='TRUE' AND control1=0 )
     THEN 
      UPDATE SecondTable SET COUNTER=(bRow.Counter+1) 
            WHERE ROWID=bRow.rowid;
```

This will give you the fastest means of locating the row that you want to update.

Comment: I will try that but there is no rowid in that table. Should change my table design or you mean oracle's rowid?

Comment: I try that but bRow.rowid doesn't work. It says bRow.rowid must be declared.

Comment: @ArdahanKisbet, try replacing the first line in the code snippet with `FOR bRow IN (SELECT mi_prinx, startend, geoloc, counter, rowid FROM SecondTable)`

Comment: You can also write the selects in the inner loop as one statement for a (possibly miniscule) performance improvement: `select SDO_GEOM.RELATE(aRow.Startpoint,'anyinteract', SDO_LRS.geom_segment_start_pt(bRow.Geoloc),0.02), SDO_GEOM.RELATE(aRow.Endpoint,'anyinteract', SDO_LRS.geom_segment_end_pt(bRow.Geoloc),0.02) into resultForStart, resultForEnd from dual;`

Comment: Thank you a lot. For 100 record it speed up 2 seconds.

Comment: @DavidAldridge, the cursor probably needs to be `for bRow IN (select t.*, t.rowid as rwd from secondtable t)`, then within the loop we can refer to bRow.rwd.